# How can I combine these two JavaScript objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge

I have two JavaScript objects as follows;

```
cages = [
  {
    "id":1,
    "name":"Cage 1"
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "name":"Cage 2"
  }
]

animals = [
  {
    "id":1,
    "name":"doge",
    "cages": [
      {
        "id":1,
        "name":"Cage 1"
      },
      {
        "id":2,
        "name":"Cage 2"
      }
    ]
  }
  {
    "id":2,
    "name":"kat",
    "cages": [
      {
        "id":2,
        "name":"Cage 2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to add the animals to the cages object, so that I end up with;

```
cages = [
  {
    "id":1,
    "name":"Cage 1",
    "animals": [
      {
        "id":1,
        "name":"doge"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "name":"Cage 2",
    "animals": [
      {
        "id":1,
        "name":"doge"
      },
      {
        "id":2,
        "name":"kat"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What are some ways of combining two objects like this? Which ones are most efficient? My first attempt had some nested for loops that got pretty deep and messy and never quite worked. Here's some incomplete logic I've got so far;

```
for(var i=0; i<animals.length; i++) {
    for(var n=0; n<animals.cages.length) {
      cages[].push(animals[i]);
    }
  }
```

I need to know how to specify which cage to push the animal into. I wish it was as simple as `cages[cage].push(animals[i]);` but in this case the keys are the same for each cage object.

Comment: Iterate over `animals` with e.g. `i`, nested inside that, iterate over `animals[i].cages` with e.g. `j`, you should now have all the information you need to structure your data. Also, to iterate over an _Array_ you just use a normal `for`, as you can access `.length` and everything uses indices, the `for..in` is meant for generic _Objects_ where keys/property names can be any _String_

Comment: @PaulS. Using `for each(animal in animals)` is essentially the same thing as `for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++)` but I'm still not sure how to choose which object in the cages array to push the animal into.

Comment: [`for each..in` is **depreciated**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in), the similar thing in _ES6_ is `for..of`, but you should still not use either of these for an _Array_. You can't assume there isn't something enumerable in `Array.prototype`, e.g. what if for some reason you need to add a shim or polyfill for something in future `Array.prototype.contains = function contains(x) {return this.indexOf(x) !== -1};`, you'll now iterate over the function too

Comment: @PaulS. I changed the for each loop in my example. But my problem is still the same.

Comment: I think the thing I need to figure out is; 'Which index in the cages array contains an object whose value for the key "id" is x.'

Answer (score 0):

Using a nested loop

```
var i, j, k;
for (i = 0; i < animals.length; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < animals[i].cages.length; ++j) {
        // assuming cages[k].id === k
        // you may want to create a new cages object instead
        k = animals[i].cages[j].id; // neat shorthand
        if (!cages[k].animals) { // if no animals yet
            cages[k].animals = []; // initialise
        }
        cages[k].animals.push(
            { // add new animal to cage
                id: animals[i].id,
                name: animals[i].name
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: The assuming `cages[k].id === k` part is where I'm stuck, because that is not true in this case. How would I go about creating a new cages object?

Comment: Is every id unique? You may be better off using _Objects_ rather than _Arrays_

Comment: It's an Array of Objects. I'm stuck using what I have, because the original objects are coming from an api response. Every ID is unique.

Comment: I'm trying to think if I can use underscore.js to make this easier.